# Subgroups and quotient groups of finite abelian $p$-groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, p-groups

**Motivation**

The fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups gives us a concise description of the isomorphism types of finite abelian $p$-groups $G$ (in the following, $p$ is a fixed prime). The isomorphism type can be encoded in a sequence of numbers (a partition), the *type* of $G$.

Since subgroups $H$ and quotient groups $G/H$ of $G$ are again finite abelian $p$-groups, this suggests the question which types can appear for $H$ and $G/H$.

**Definition**

Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group.
By the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups, there is a unique non-increasing sequence $a = (a_0, a_1, a_2,\ldots)$ of non-negative integers such that
$$
G \cong \mathbb Z/p^{a_0}\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p^{a_1}\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/p^{a_2}\mathbb Z \times \ldots$$
This sequence is called the *type* of $G$ and will be denoted by $\operatorname{type}(G)$. We assume that the set of types is partially ordered by component-wise comparison.

Since $G$ is finite, starting with some position, all entries in the infinite sequence $\operatorname{type}(G)$ are zero. As usual in the theory of partitions, we may drop all those zero entries to represent the type with a finite non-decreasing sequence of positive integers.

**Example**

Consider $p = 2$ and $G = \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/8\mathbb Z$. Then $\operatorname{type}(G) = (3,2,2,0,0,0,\ldots) = (3,2,2)$.
This type is smaller than the type $(4,3,2)$, larger than $(3,2)$ and not comparable to $(4,2)$.

**Problem**

> Let $G$ be a finite abelian $p$-group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$.
>
> Prove or disprove:
>
> 1. $\operatorname{type}(H) \leq \operatorname{type}(G)$.
> 2. $\operatorname{type}(G/H) \leq \operatorname{type}(G)$.

---

My first feeling was that both statements should be true and not too hard to prove. I've tried to attack the problem by various inductive arguments. Maybe I'm blind, but it didn't work out so far. This leaves me wondering if (one of) the statements might actually be wrong. But I couldn't find a counterexample, either.

To document a failed attempt which came up in the discussion below:
By the type of $G$, it is not hard to count the number of elements of a certain order in $G$.

- For example, a group of type $(2,2)$ has $1$ element of order $1$, $p^2 - 1$ elements of order $p$ and $p^4 - p^2$ elements of order $p^2$.
  A group of type $(1,1,1)$ has $1$ element of order $1$ and $p^3 - 1$ elements of order $p$. Since $p^3 - 1 > p^2 - 1$, this shows that a group of type $(2,2)$ doesn't have a subgroup of type $(1,1,1)$.
- However, the comparison of the number of elements of a certain order is not enough to derive the claimed statement 1. For example, type $(2,1,1,1)$ has $p^4 - 1$ elements of order $p$ and $p^5 - p^4$ elements of order $p^2$. These two numbers are larger than those for type $(2,2)$ above. So for a group of type $(2,1,1,1)$, the subgroup type $(2,2)$ cannot be eliminated in this way.

Comment: Which ordering are you putting on the partitions?

Comment: perhaps I'm missing something, but isn't a little weird to define that apparently infinite type sequence of a finite abelian p- group in a *decreasing* order? You **must** then know what the highest number (exponent of p) appears to begin with the sequence...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: As written in the definition-part: Component-wise comparison. So it is a partial order. For example, $(2,2,1) \leq (3,2,1,1)$, but $(3,2,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ are not comparable.

Comment: @DonAntonio: Of course, you can start with finite non-zero sequences, too. I went with the infinite version since it makes the definition of the order very natural. Otherwise, you have to say something about sequences of different length.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that somehow (I usually denote that ordering by $\subseteq$). Then it should be clear that both statements are true (note that any quotient of an abelian group is isomorphic to a subgroup as well, so we only need to do one of them).

Comment: Oh, it's not the finite-infinite thing that bothers me, @azimut, but the order in it: why non-increasing instead of non-decreasing, what I'd say is more natural in this case? Perhaps it's just a matter of taste or perhaps there's something I can't see so far.

Comment: @DonAntonio If it was to be non-decreasing, you could not let it end in $0$'s.

Comment: @DonAntonio: sorry, I misread your comment. Still, the decreasing order makes the comparison more natural.

Comment: Oh, I see now: because of the ordering defined. Thanks. @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: I have deleted my answer as it turned out to be way off. And so was my comment about element orders it turns out. At least the number of elements of order $p$ determines the length of the partition, but that is the best I can come up with right now. I think the number of elements of order $p^m$ determines the number of entries that are $\geq m$, given the number of entries $\geq m'$ for all $m' < m$, but I need to think a bit more about how.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: You indicated that there is a character theoretic proof of the property that every quotient group of an abelian group is isomorphic to a subgroup. May I ask you to give some details on this? Thank you!

Comment: The proof I know goes by showing first that the set of homomorphisms from an abelian group to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to the group itself with usual multiplication (the proof can be done by induction on the number of cyclic groups in the decomposition and by checking that the "obvious" map then becomes injective, and the surjective part then follows by a counting argument). The proof then goes by noticing that given a subgroup, one gets the quotient by that subgroup as a subgroup of the group of homomorphisms (as the set of those homomorphisms vanishing on the given subgroup).

Comment: I think I'm correct in saying that this question has recently been answered in a different post. See here for details : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/744999/abelian-p-groups

Comment: @MichaelPounds: Thanks for informing me. Seems that the linked question is essentially the same as the first part of this question. However, additionally I've asked for quotient groups. As far as I see, this second part is not covered by your question. I'm quite envy that you got more attention than me... :)

Answer (score 2):

For the simplicity of symbol, write $A^l=\{ a^{p^l} | a \in A \}$ for the abelian $p$-group. Let $type(G) =(n_1, n_2, \cdots, n_r)$ and $type(G/H)=(m_1, m_2, \cdots, m_r)$. Suppose that for some $t$, $n_i \ge m_i$ ($i =1, \cdots, t$), but $m_{t+1}>n_{t+1}$. Let $l=n_{t+1}$. Now consider $G^l$ and $ (G/H)^l$. Clearly $G^l$ is the direct product of $t$ cyclic sugroups, and $(G/H)^l$ is the direct product with at least $t+1$ factors. This means $G^l$ can be generated by $t$ elements, but $(G/H)^l$ can not be generated by $t$ elements.  Note that $(G/H)^l=G^lH/H \cong G^l/(G^l \cap H)$, wich can be generated by $t$ elements. This contradiction completes the proof of your problem 2.

Of course, problem 1 can be prove as  Michael Pounds's comments.