# Is a subgroup of a product of two groups necessarily a product of two subgroups ?

Tags: group-theory

Is a subgroup of a product of two groups necessarily a product of two subgroups  ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Do you mind clarifying your question a little? Is your product a *direct product*? If my product of two groups is $G \times H$, then are you asking for two subgroups of $G$ **and/or** $H$? And by saying group $A$ *is* $B$, do you mean they are isomorphic?

Comment: @Myridium-Yeah i mean a direct product and i'm asking for two subgroups of G AND H. I'm so sorry because i only study mathematics in french and i never had the chance to define these English terms.Thanks a lot.

Comment: How's this then? **Is a subgroup $S \leq G \times H$ isomorphic to $A \times B$ for some $A \leq G$ and $B \leq H$?**

Comment: $S_3 \times S_3$ has a subgroup of index $2$ which is not isomorphic to a direct product of two subgroups of $S_3$.

Comment: Related if you are talking about isomorphisms : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529023

Comment: Have a look at Goursat's theorem that is generalized in (https://arxiv.org/abs/1109.0024)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is any subgroup of a direct product isomorphic to a direct product of subgroups?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529023/is-any-subgroup-of-a-direct-product-isomorphic-to-a-direct-product-of-subgroups)

Comment: @Watson: Not just related but is a duplicate of.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, Consider the subgroup of $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ generated by $(1,1)$

Comment: This is the product of $\mathbb Z$ with $\{1\}$.

Comment: @Myridium what substance are you on?

Comment: Am I making a dumb mistake? The way I interpret the OP's question is such that in this case, they are looking for a direct product of subgroups of $\mathbb Z$ isomorphic to the subgroup of $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ generated by $(1,1)$ (which is $\mathbb Z$).

Comment: Oh ok, I guess that makes sense. I'll try to come up with something under that interpretation.

Comment: What about this subgroup of Z² : {(x, x) / x in Z}  ?

Comment: @ZakariaOussaad - That is $\mathbb Z^2$ which is $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. The only subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$ are $\{1\}$, $\mathbb Z$ and $\mathbb Z^2$, so this may not be a good example.