# Subgroups of $G^n$, where $G$ is a $p$-group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be a finite $p$-group and let $n > 0$. Let $G^n$ be the direct product of $n$ copies of $G$.

> Are all subgroups of $G^n$ isomorphic to $H_1 \times \dotsm \times H_n$ for some subgroups $H_1, \dots, H_n$
>   of $G$?

**Comments**. The question is being *isomorphic* to a direct product of subgroups, and not being *equal* to a direct product of subgroups. A negative answer to a similar question for $G = S_3$ and $n = 2$ was given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/529161). 
This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/485512/subgroups-of-a-direct-product) and its [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/488222), which relies on [Goursat's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goursat%27s_lemma) might also be relevant.

P.S. I am especially interested in the case $p = 2$.

Comment: Have you run any computer checks for small values of $|G|$ and $n$?

Comment: I tried a few examples on GAP without finding any counterexample so far.

Comment: I doubt this is true, but I could be wrong. Include the code you have used to check this, if you want, and we can split the workload. (I was just about to start thinking how to write a piece of GAP code that would work, so it would save me some time.)

Comment: I have replaced "Is any" in your question by "Are all". The word "any" is very often ambiguous.

Comment: @derek-holt Thanks a lot, Derek.

Comment: I think $D_8 \times D_8$ has a subdirect product of index 2 that does not decompose as a nontrivial direct product. (Here $D_8$ means dihedral group of order $8$.)

Comment: I am not finding any built-in function in GAP which checks if a group is directly decomposable, but you may want to check if a subgroup of a direct product is isomorphic to a group with a unique minimal normal subgroup.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $G=D_8 = \langle a,b \mid a^4=b^2=(ab)^2=1 \rangle$, $G^2 = \langle a_1,b_1\rangle \times \langle a_2,b_2 \rangle$  and $H = \langle a_1a_2,b_1,b_2,a_1^2,a_2^2 \rangle \le G$ with $|H|=32$.

If $H \cong H_1 \times H_2$, with $H_1$ and $H_2$ isomorphic to subgroups of $D_8$, then we must have $|H_1|=8$, $|H_2|=4$ (or vice versa), so $H_2$ is abelian, and hence $|Z(H_1 \times H_2)| =8$. But you can check that $Z(H)=Z(G) = \langle a_1^2,a_2^2 \rangle$ has order $4$.

In fact $H$ is indecomposable.