# $G\cong(G\cap A)\times(G\cap B)$ where $G\subseteq(A\times B)$ and $(|A|,|B|)=1$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a subgroup of the direct product $A\times B$, and assume that the groups $A$ and $B$ have relatively prime orders.

> Prove that $G\cong(G\cap A)\times(G\cap B)$.

I reasoned like this: $G$ consists elements $(a,b)$, where $a\in A$ and $b\in B$. Then $G\cap A$ consists elements $(a,e_B)$ and $G\cap B$ consists elements $(e_A,b)$. It means $(G\cap A)\subseteq A$ and $(G\cap B)\subseteq B$. We have subgroup in $A$ and subgroup in $B$.

Then $(G\cap A)\times(G\cap B)\subseteq(A\times B)$. I think that $G=(G\cap A)\times(G\cap B)$ but I don't know how to prove this fact. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $G$? ${}$

Comment: 1) What is $G?$ 2) What progress does the remaining of your post add to the question of your 2 first lines? It doesn't seem to show any attempt at all.

Comment: How is defined the intersection of $D$ (subgroup of $A\times B$) with $A$?

Comment: @Deif It cannot mean anything else than: $A$ is  identified with $A\times\{e_B\}.$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/748531/subgroups-of-direct-products

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may write $(a,b)\in G$ as $(a,b)=(a,1_B)(1_A,b)$. Your claim follows easily if we prove that $(a,1_B)\in G\cap A$ and $(1_A,b)=G\cap B$. We prove the first case, since the second one is analogous. We have
$$(a,b)^{|B|}=(a^{|B|},b^{|B|})=(a^{|B|},1_B)\in G\cap A.$$
Furthermore, since $(|A|,|B|)=1$ there exist $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb Z$ such that $\alpha|A|+\beta|B|=1$. Now, note that $(a,b)^{\beta|B|}=(a^{\beta|B|},1_B)\in G\cap A$ and hence
$$(a^{1-\alpha|A|},1_B)=(a(a^{|A|})^{-\alpha},1_B)=(a,1_B)\in G\cap A,$$
as desired.